# Can't get input fields on right side to shift up. Also, need last AM/PM button to shift right (below blue box)

Tags: html, css

I've tried floating the "sections" to the left and the .defaultCalc and userInputs to the right, but it became a mess. I was able to get them to somewhat align the way I need them by using text-align left and text-align right. I'm not sure if its best practice but its working as of now.

My issue is that I can't get the ride side column to shift up so it can align with the questions. Also, the AM/PM buttons on the bottom should be right under the blue box (just like the AM/PM buttons above). This is for the media query section for screen sizes bigger than 768px. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```css
/*Base style layouts*/

header,
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #edf0f1;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #95989A;
  text-align: center;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Gray areas that display javascript calculations*/

.defaultCalc {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*Sections that require the user to input a number*/

.userInput::placeholder {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(149, 152, 154, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.userInput {
  border: 1px solid #D3D8DB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Buttons*/

.amButton,
.pmButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.calcButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 217px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.clockOutTime {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #60B6FF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clockOutAMButton,
.clockOutPMButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: #15D1BC;
  outline: none;
}

.pmButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.amButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.calcButton:active {
  font-size: 1.075em;
}


/*Media Queries*/

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  header {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .sections {
    text-align: left;
  }
  body {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .calculate {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .buttons {
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300i,400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

  <title>40 Hour Workweek Calculator</title>

</head>


<body>

  <header>
    <h3>40-Hour Workweek Calculator</h3>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">


    <h4 class="sections">Total hours needed to work this week:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 40" />

    <h4 class="sections">On Friday morning, how many hours<br />(in whole numbers) do you currently have?</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 33" />

    <h4 class="sections">Enter remaining decimals:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: .57" />

    <h4 class="sections">Converted to time format:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Remaining hours to work:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter time you clocked in on Friday:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 7:22" /><br />

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="amButton">AM</button>
      <button class="pmButton">PM</button>
    </div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter today's lunch break in minutes:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 30" />

    <div class="sections calculate">
      <button class="calcButton">Calculate my hours</button>
    </div>

    <h4 class="sections">Time to clock out on Friday:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc clockOutTime"></div>

    <div class="sections">
      <div class="clockOutAMButton">AM</div>
      <div class="clockOutPMButton">PM</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

[This is the original design I'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z66R.png)

Comment: Can you attach an image of expected behaviour? It's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's the original design:

Answer (score 0):

Your `/*Media Queries*/` seems odd, I updated few place, make sure your regular CSS are at top of your style sheet, then you go query for small screen size, and overwrite the CSS you need to.

Let me know if this is close to what you are looking for.

```css
/*Base style layouts*/

header,
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #edf0f1;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #95989A;
  text-align: center;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*Gray areas that display javascript calculations*/

.defaultCalc {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*Sections that require the user to input a number*/

.userInput::placeholder {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(149, 152, 154, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.userInput {
  border: 1px solid #D3D8DB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}


/*Buttons*/

.amButton,
.pmButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.buttons {
  margin: -15px 0 25px 0;
}

.calcButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 217px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.clockOutTime {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #60B6FF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clockOutAMButton,
.clockOutPMButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: #15D1BC;
  outline: none;
}

.pmButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.amButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.calcButton:active {
  font-size: 1.075em;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*Media Queries*/

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  header {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .sections {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
  .defaultCalc {
      margin-left: 10%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .userInput {
    margin-left: 10%;
   display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .calculate {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .buttons {
   margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    float: left;
  display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300i,400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

<title>40 Hour Workweek Calculator</title>


<body>

  <header>
    <h3>40-Hour Workweek Calculator</h3>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">


    <h4 class="sections">Total hours needed to work this week:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 40" />

    <h4 class="sections">On Friday morning, how many hours<br />(in whole numbers) do you currently have?</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 33" />

    <h4 class="sections">Enter remaining decimals:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: .57" />

    <h4 class="sections">Converted to time format:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Remaining hours to work:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter time you clocked in on Friday:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 7:22" />
    <br />

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="amButton">AM</button>
      <button class="pmButton">PM</button>
    </div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter today's lunch break in minutes:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 30" />

    <div class="sections calculate">
      <button class="calcButton">Calculate my hours</button>
    </div>

    <br />
    <h4 class="sections">Time to clock out on Friday:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc clockOutTime"></div>

    <div class="sections">
      <div class="clockOutAMButton">AM</div>
      <div class="clockOutPMButton">PM</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Daniel. Your response is pretty close to what I'm looking for but not exactly. I've added an image of the original design in my post. My CSS was made for mobile view and then the media query was for larger screens. Maybe that's why it looks a little odd?

When I run your new code, the layout and alignment for the mobile view are out of place.

Comment: @lgrizo what size of the screen?

Comment: For screens 768px and smaller, I wanted just one column. For anything bigger, I want 2 columns. Questions on the left and inout fields on the right. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who chimed in. I was finally able to figure out how to make the input sections show up to the right of each question. I ended up enclosing each section with a  and then changing the display properties within each div to inline-block so they would appear next to each other. Then I text-aligned the questions to the left, and added padding right so the input fields would move to the right 75px. Just in case anyone is interested, here is my current code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>40 Hour Workweek Calculator</title>

</head>


<body>

  <header>
    <h3>40-Hour Workweek Calculator</h3>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections totalHours">How many hours do you plan on working this week?</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" id="hoursWeek" placeholder="ex: 40" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections fridayHours">On Friday morning, how many hours<br />(in whole numbers) do you currently have?</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" id="fridayMorning" placeholder="ex: 33" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections remDecimal">Enter remaining decimals:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" id="remainingDecimals" placeholder="ex: .57" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections convertedTime">Converted to time format:</h4>
      <div class="defaultCalc" id="convertToTime"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections remainHours">Remaining hours to work:</h4>
      <div class="defaultCalc" id="remainingHours"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections clockFriday">Enter time you clocked in on Friday:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" id="enterClockIn" placeholder="ex: 7:22" /><br />
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="amButton">AM</button>
      <button class="pmButton">PM</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections lunch">Enter today's lunch break in minutes:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" id="enterLunch" placeholder="ex: 30" />
    </div>

    <div class="sections calculate">
      <button class="calcButton" id="clickCalc">Calculate my hours</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4 class="sections outFriday">Time to clock out on Friday:</h4>
      <div class="defaultCalc clockOutTime" id="clockOutToday"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="lastButtons">
      <div class="clockOutAMButton">AM</div>
      <div class="clockOutPMButton">PM</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



/*Base style layouts*/

header, body {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #edf0f1;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #96deda 0%, #50c9c3 40%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Gray areas that display javascript calculations*/

.defaultCalc {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 29px;
}


/*Sections that require the user to input a number*/

.userInput::placeholder {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(149, 152, 154, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.userInput {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 14.5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Buttons*/

.amButton, .pmButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.calcButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #50c9c3;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.clockOutTime {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #60B6FF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clockOutAMButton, .clockOutPMButton {
  width: 45px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.calcButton:active {
  font-size: 1.075em;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 520px;
  }
  .totalHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .fridayHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .remDecimal {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .convertedTime {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .remainHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .clockFriday {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .buttons {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 380px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }

  .amButton, .pmButton {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .lunch {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .outFriday {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .lastButtons {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 380px;
  }
  .outFriday {
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .clockOutAMButton, .clockOutPMButton {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .sections, .clockOutTime, .defaultCalc {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .calcButton {
    width: 520px;
  }

}
```